# What assigns timestamps to read-only transactions in Spanner?

Tags: distributed-transactions, google-cloud-spanner

The Spanner paper makes it clear that commit timestamps are chosen for read-write transactions by the coordinator leader. However, I'm not sure of where the timestamps are chosen for read-only transactions.

The documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/whitepapers/life-of-reads-and-writes#strong_read_multi-node) says:

> API Layer will pick the read timestamp by using the current TrueTime.

But where is that API layer situated? Does that refer to the location proxy that the paper says clients use to locate the relevant spanservers? The paper says it uses TT.now().latest but I can't tell where that gets invoked.

I had assumed that the timestamp could be chosen by any of the Paxos leaders involved in the multi-site read, but apparently not. Can someone please help clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But where is that API layer situated? Does that refer to the location proxy that the paper says clients use to locate the relevant spanservers?

That's correct, it's in the API proxy.

> I had assumed that the timestamp could be chosen by any of the Paxos leaders involved in the multi-site read, but apparently not.

To negotiate a timestamp, strong read requests must contact the Paxos leader for **each** Spanner group involved in that read.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Just to confirm your last point, the paper says:

"If the scope’s values are served by multiple Paxos
groups, there are several options. The most complicated
option is to do a round of communication with all of
the groups’s leaders to negotiate sread based on LastTS().
Spanner currently implements a simpler choice. The
client avoids a negotiation round, and just has its reads
execute at sread = TT.now().latest..."


It seems like they have decided to go with the more complex option since the paper was released, is that right?

Comment: For strong read - yes, it has to contact all the Paxos group leaders, which is the more complex option described here.